# Add third party Self signed certificate in JBoss EAP 7.2.0

Tags: spring-boot, https, certificate, keystore, jboss-eap-7

I am developing a Spring Boot application and deploying it in JBoss EAP 7.2.0 server. From my application I am calling another application using REST over HTTPS. I have the certificate (.crt file) and key (.key file) of the third party application. Can anyone please guide me how to add this to the keystore of JBoss EAP 7.2.0 so that I can call the third party application?